# How to call a CollectionViewController from within a collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a swift file that is a class type UICollectionViewCell and I have a button that I want to call another view that is a collectionviewcontroller.
How do I do this?

I am trying to do this but I can't finish this function

```
func handleStartButtonClick(){
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let mainViewController = MainViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a delegate protocol and your controller should conform to that protocol. Then you declare a variable of that delegate in your cell and in cellforitemat function you do something like this:
in your CollectionViewCell swift file, out of your class declare a protocol:

```
protocol MyCollectionViewCellDelegate {
    func someThingThatMyControllerShouldDo()
}

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

}
```

then inside your CollectionViewCell class:

```
var delegate: MyCollectionViewCellDelegate?
```

in cellForItemAt function of your Controller you can initialize this variable's value to your controller:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

then in your CollectionViewCell when ever you want your controller to do something, you just call your delegate's functions:

```
self.delegate?.someFunctionDeclaredInDelegate()
```

and of course your ViewController must conform to this protocol, it means it should implement those methods of protocol:

```
extension MyViewController: MyCollectionViewDelegate {
    func someThingThatMyControllerShouldDo() {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowMySecondController", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to this protocol and swift. I am having a hard time understanding how I would call another collectionViewController from a collectionviewcell that is generated by another collectionViewController. I did what you said but I am having an error can not assign a value of type IntroAppCollectionViewController to the type MyCollectionCellDelegate?

Comment: it's totally ok mate, I was in your situation about 4 month ago, as I said in my answer your controller should conform to protocol, this means this controller should implement functions of protocol, you should extend your controller as I wrote for you

Comment: extension MyViewController: MyCollectionViewDelegate {
    func someThingThatMyControllerShouldDo() {
        // code here
    }
}

Comment: Why do I need protocols to segue from one collectionViewController to another?If it was a ViewController I would use presentViewController and it would do what I want.

Comment: you need protocol to send message between collectionviewcell and collectionviewcontroller. I didn't suggest protocol to segue between controllers

Comment: I need to segue between two collectionviewcontrollers. How would I do that? I tried to use present but there is no method like there is on viewfontrollers

Comment: you have a collectionViewController and you want when it's cell clicked, to go to another viewController, right?

Comment: I have one collectionviewcontroller and when i click a button i want to go to another collectionviewcontroller

Comment: you can use didSelectItemAt function of CollectionView and performSegue function of Controller to do your job.

Comment: I can't find this didSelectItemAt inside my UICollectionViewCell.I do find it inside my UICollectionViewController but I have a button inside my cell and that is what I am using to trigger the call to another UICollectionViewcontroller.

Comment: Hi the protocol definition should be class bound and will change from:
protocol MyCollectionViewCellDelegate { }
to:
protocol MyCollectionViewCellDelegate: class { }

also the delegate should be a weak one so it will change from
var delegate: MyCollectionViewCellDelegate?
to:
weak var delegate: MyCollectionViewCellDelegate?

If you do not do this the cell will have a strong reference to the ViewController and will cause a memory leak because of a retain cycle.  @JafarKhoshtabiat Please update the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer for you, if you want an element inside cell and you want to trigger action from that, you need delegate.